# Collision detection in Cocos2d JS game

Tags: collision-detection, cocos2d-js

In my `Cocos2d-JS` game I have two node(triangles) and I want to *detect a collision* between them i.e when one moves over the other?

I could not find any help in the API provided. How do i proceed?

```
var top = new cc.DrawNode();
var points=[cc.p(0,0), cc.p(5,0),cc.p(2.5,5)];
top.drawPoly(points, cc.color(255,0,0,255), 3, cc.color(255,255,255,255));
top.x =size.width/2;
top.y =size.height;
top.rotation=180;
top.anchorX=0.5;
top.anchorY=1;
var left = new cc.DrawNode();
var points=[cc.p(0,0), cc.p(0,5),cc.p(5,2.5)];
left.drawPoly(points, cc.color(0,0,0,255), 3, cc.color(255,255,255,255));
left.x =0;
left.y =size.height/2;
left.anchorX=0;
left.anchorY=0.5;
```

Now when top moves over left i want to detect the collision??

Comment: I have added the code.. "Lea Tano

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 choices here:

a. Create your custom polygon-collision-detection code
b. Use the `cc.rectIntersectsRect(top, left)` to treat the triangles as squares by their bounding box
c. Use Chimpmunk or Box2D to handle collision detection for you

All 3 alternatives are discussed in [this forum thread](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-make-a-visible-rectangle-use-for-creating-bounding-box-for-collision/19638).